# Are these two limits equal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, summation

The problem basically goes as follows:

Let $x_i$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $f : \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$ be a bijection.
And finally, let $h : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ be some function.

I want to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left({\sum_{i = 1}^n {h(x_i)}}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left({\sum_{i = 1}^n {h(x_{f(i)})}}\right)$$

I require this result to solve some other problem so I dont actually know if this is true or not. If it is, how do I start with the proof? I have thought of a few ways (one of them was to try to get somewhere with $\sum_{i = 1}^n ({h(x_i) + h(x_{f(i)}))}$ but that did not really help). My intuition tells me that it should be true because, roughly speaking, since $f$ is a bijection, in the limiting case, "all" of the terms will be same on both sides.

Comment: The result is false. See [conditional convergence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence).

Comment: It is true iff the series is absolutely convergent

Comment: If $h(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ then this is true and standard.

Comment: @lorago so if the function h has a range of just positive real numbers then it is true right?

Comment: @eipim1 yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not always true. But it is true if the series is absolutely convergent — that is, if the sum of absolute values converges:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty |h(x_i)| < \infty $$

In particular, if $h$ is never negative and the series converges, then any permutation of the series also converges to the same value.

For a counterexample with mixed signs in the sequence, let the sequence $\{ h(x_i) \}$ be the alternating harmonic series:
$$h(x_i) = \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}$$

which is known to sum to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i} = \ln 2 $$

(The $x_i$ values don't matter, since we can just look at the resulting sequence $h(x_i)$.)

For the bijection $f$, we'll use one that includes two negative terms for every positive term (like a [Hilbert's Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) rearrangement):

$$ \begin{align*} f(3k+1) &= 2k+1 \\
f(3k+2) &= 4k+2 \\
f(3k+3) &= 4k+4
\end{align*} $$

So the permuted sequence starts

$$ \{h(x_{f(i)})\}: \frac{1}{1}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{6}, -\frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{5}, -\frac{1}{10}, -\frac{1}{12}, \ldots $$

The sum of this sequence is

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty h(x_{f(i)}) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \big(h(x_{f(3k+1)}) + h(x_{f(3k+2)}) + h(x_{f(3k+3)})\big) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{4k+2} - \frac{1}{4k+4}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4k+2} - \frac{1}{4k+4}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k+1} - \frac{1}{2k+2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j} \\
\sum_{i=1}^\infty h(x_{f(i)}) &= \frac{1}{2} \ln 2
\end{align*} $$

See also the Wikipedia articles on [absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence) and the [Reimann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).